# Learning C# after C++

Tags: c#, c++

In a progression of languages, I have been learning C and C++.  Now I would like to learn C#.  I know there are some drastic differences between them - such as the removal of pointers and garbage collection.  However, I don't know many of the differences between the two.

What are the major differences that a C++ programmer would need to know when moving to C#?  (For example, what can I use instead of STL, syntactic differences between them, or anything else that might be considered important.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[C# for C++ Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b(v=vs.90).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a great place to start.  It is a table that lists the most important comparisons between the two languages.

Once you have explored some of these differences, you might choose a self-contained project you have written in the past in C++, and re-write it in C#.  In your first pass, you will probably just end up translating directly across, using the same design and algorithms.  As you become more comfortable with C#, you will recognize ways to take advantage of language features only available in C#, as well as the incredibly versatile .NET Framework.

Comment: definately read a good book about .net so you can take full value of the framework. I have taken the same step youre about to take and i suggest reading ProC# 2008 by Andrew Troelsen. Maybe there is already a new Edition of that book.

Comment: As old as this question and answer are, it's worth noting that the linked article is now outdated in some regards.  For example, the article claims "In C#, method parameters cannot have default values.", but this is no longer true as of C# 4.0.

Comment: Is there a new version?

Comment: Here is the updated link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b(v=vs.90).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for C# for C++ developers

Answer (score 6):

I think it's important to note that pointers weren't really *removed* from C#, but that they still exist, they are everywhere, and they are called **references**.

Comment: I know they are still there - computers can't work without 'em.  What really seems to have happened is that the difference between an object and a pointer to that object is hidden.  Mostly.

Comment: Classic pointers are direct memory addresses of the location of particular object or vpiece of data. The CLR can reorder the objects in memory to compact the heap; thus a reference to an object does not necessarily reflect its position in the memory.

Comment: And you can use pointers in C#, the code just has to be marked unsafe. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Charles Petzold has a [.NET Book Zero](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/index.html) that is designed specifically for the C/C++ Windows programmer who wants to learn C# and .NET.  It is a free PDF download from his site.  All of the source code used in the book is available as a separate Zip-file download.

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Comment: @RedX the link is OK

Answer (score 3):

There was a similar question that has lots of pointers (pun inteded :-)) and resources about the differences between C++ and C# and what to pay attention when learning transitioning - [Linux/C++ programmer to Windows/C# programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131589/linuxc-programmer-to-cwindows-programmer).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Generic collections and LINQ (all the related technology to LINQ) for STL like functionality.

The number one thing to note is that ~/Destructor is c++ is nothing like the ~/finalizer in c# -- See IDisposable/using.